# No map, only coastlines when browsing slippymap

Tags: openstreetmap

I am working on creating an OpenStreetMap tile server on CentOS 6.4. All that I get when loading the slippymap.html page for the "local tiles" layer is a map with just two colors white and blue for the land and water. That is, I see an image basically of the coastlines. The "mapnik" layer works fine.

This is the first time I am doing software configuration related to maps. All terms like mapnik, osm2pgsql, postgis, tile and so on are new to me.

As far as I have seen from google search results, there does not seem to be readily available information on creating this server on CentOS 6.x. So, for me, the main set of instructions has been the following document:

http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/ [1]

All the components either had to be installed from third-party CentOS repositories like ELGIS, RPMForge, EPEL and PGDG92 or compiled from source.

A few days back, I did create the same server on Ubuntu 12.04, which was straightforward. These instructions were followed:

http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/ [2]

Note that document [2] mentions about accessing the slippymap.html but [1] does not. In [1], the only test mentioned is accessing yourserveraddress/osm_tiles/0/0/0.png which works fine even in my CentOS 6.4 setup. I created the slippymap.html by copying from the Ubuntu 12.04 box and minor editing.

One more piece of information that could be a crucial clue is the following error from renderd:

proj_init_error:failed to initialize projection with: '+init=epsg:4326'

I do have proj and proj-devel packages installed.

$ ldd /usr/local/bin/renderd | grep proj
        libproj.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libproj.so.0 (0x00007ffa42a0e000)

How do I debug this issue? What could be the problem? Are there any checklists to verify the proper functioning of each of the components like osm2pgsql, the postgres/postgis db, mod_tile or mapnik?

Comment: I suggest to re-ask your question on http://help.openstreetmap.org or http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok. Have been able to find a solution (see, answer).

Answer (score 1):

I debugged this issue and came to understand the mapnik sources from the 2.0.x branch of the Git repo, git://github.com/mapnik/mapnik call pj_init_plus_ctx() that fails. See, code snipped for more info.

```
/*
 * Demonstrate mapnik 2.0 against proj 4.8.0-2 bug.
 *
 * Mapnik makes use of pj_init_plus_ctx() if the PJ_VERSION macro is >= 480,
 * which fails. Otherwise, it calls pj_init_plus(), which succeeds.
 */

#include <proj_api.h>

int main(void)
{
    projCtx ctx = NULL;
    projPJ proj = NULL;
#if 0
    projPJ p = NULL;
#endif

    ctx = pj_ctx_alloc();
    /* proj is NULL after this call */
    proj = pj_init_plus_ctx(ctx, "+init=epsg:4326");

#if 0
    /* p is not NULL after this call */
    p = pj_init_plus("+init=epsg:4326");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

I have been able to forge ahead by changing PJ_VERSION in /usr/include/pj_api.h to 470. Did face another error which was fixed was setting font_dir to "/usr/local/lib64/mapnik/fonts" in /etc/renderd.conf. Now names of places, state boundaries, roadways, etc are getting displayed.